# Celery limit number of specific task in queue

Tags: python, queue, task, celery, worker

I'm using Celery 3.1.x with 2 tasks. The first task (TaskOne) is enqueued when Celery starts up through the celeryd_after_setup signal:

```
@celeryd_after_setup.connect
def celeryd_after_setup(*args, **kwargs):
    TaskOne().apply_async(countdown=5)
```

When TaskOne is run, it does some calculations and then enqueues TaskTwo. Imagine the following workflow:

- I start celery, thus the signal is fired and  TaskOne is enqueued
- after the countdown (5) TaskTwo is enqueued
- then I stop celery (the TaskTwo remains in the queue)
- afterwards I restart celery
- the workflow is run again and TaskTwo is enqueued again

So we have 2 TaskTwo in the queue. That is a problem for my workflow because I only want one TaskTwo within the queue and avoid that a second one is enqueued.

My question: How can I achieve this?

With `celery.app.control.Inspect.scheduled()` ([Docs](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.control.html?highlight=inspect#celery.app.control.Control.inspect)) I can get a list of which tasks are scheduled, hidden in a combination of lists and dicts. This is maybe a way, but going through the result of this does not feel right. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After considering several options I chose to use [app.control.inspect](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html?highlight=revoke#dump-of-scheduled-eta-tasks).
It's not a really beautiful solution, but it works:

```
# fetch all scheduled tasks
scheduled_tasks = inspect().scheduled()

# iterate the scheduled task values, see http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html?highlight=revoke#dump-of-scheduled-eta-tasks
for task_values in iter(scheduled_tasks.values()):
    # task_values is a list of dicts
    for task in task_values:
        if task['request']['name'] == '{}.{}'.format(TaskTwo.__module__, TaskTwo.__name__):
            logger.info('TaskTwo is already scheduled, skipping additional run')
                return
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy-to-implement solution would be to add the [--purge](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.worker.html?highlight=purge#cmdoption-celery-worker--purge) switch to your worker command. It will clear the queue and the worker start with no scheduled jobs.

But beware: that's a kind of job-global, unrecoverable action. When there are other scheduled jobs you depend on, this is not your solution.